# Washed out colors when reproducing 2017 figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap, imshow

In April 2017 I used the following code to produce the following figure:

```
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(result, cmap = 'hot', aspect = 'equal')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('p1.png')
```

[image: April 2017 figure]

Here `result` is a 500 x 500 numpy array of floats in the range 0.55 to 0.6.

I wished to reproduce the figure at a larger resolution (using `dpi = 200` in savefig) but when re-running the same code the colors look far worse, among other differences which I am not concerned about. Notably the black region of the data doesn't look black at all, and the colors look unsaturated and washed out:

[image: October 2023 figure]

Strangely the colorbar to the right looks unchanged; and I don't think the `hot` cmap has changed in the last 6 years. Just the figure colors are changed. It is possible aspects of my matplotlib (current version: 3.7.2) system configuration have changed. Maybe there is some gamma correction setting somewhere that I had used in 2017 and have forgotten about since.

I would like to recreate the 2017 appearance of this figure, or failing that, improve the appearance of the colors (eg so that the colors in the figure are better saturated).

Comment: You could try `plt.imshow(..., interpolation='nearest')`. Nowadays, the default interpolation is "antialised", which smooths the colors.

Comment: Thank you, the problem with the colors was due to interpolation mode. Using 'none' gave me the best match to the 2017 plot although not quite the same. I don't know how to mark your comment as the solution.

Comment: You can only accept answers, not comments. You can click the up-arrow by the comment to show it's useful. @JohanC can post an answer, or close the question as a duplicate if there's already a question / answer to this.

Comment: Thanks but there is no such up arrow, only a flag and the number 1.

Comment: You need a certain reputation level I guess.